# Configuring a Liferay WSRP Consumer with a JBoss WSRP Producer

Tags: web-services, soap, jboss, liferay, wsrp

I am migrating an application from IBM Websphere to JBoss Portal. This is a portal application and I'm experiencing some authentication issues it seems. I have a WSRP producer on JBoss and a consumer on a separate Liferay (Tomcat) instance. When creating the Liferay consumer the WSDL url is not accessible. From JBoss `server.log`:

```
12:35:18,561 WARNING [org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain] (http-/127.0.0.1:8080-7) Interceptor for {urn:oasis:names:tc:wsrp:v2:wsdl}WSRPService#{urn:oasis:names:tc:wsrp:v2:intf}getServiceDescription has thrown exception, unwinding n
ow: org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.SoapFault: An error was discovered processing the <wsse:Security> header.
    at org.apache.cxf.ws.security.wss4j.WSS4JInInterceptor.createSoapFault(WSS4JInInterceptor.java:874)
    at org.apache.cxf.ws.security.wss4j.WSS4JInInterceptor.handleMessage(WSS4JInInterceptor.java:329)
    at org.jboss.wsf.stack.cxf.security.authentication.SubjectCreatingInterceptor.handleMessage(SubjectCreatingInterceptor.java:101)
    at org.gatein.wsrp.wss.cxf.producer.GTNSubjectCreatingInterceptor.handleMessage(GTNSubjectCreatingInterceptor.java:89) [wsrp-wss-jboss7-2.3.4.Final-redhat-1.jar:2.3.4.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.gatein.wsrp.wss.cxf.producer.GTNSubjectCreatingInterceptor.handleMessage(GTNSubjectCreatingInterceptor.java:49) [wsrp-wss-jboss7-2.3.4.Final-redhat-1.jar:2.3.4.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:272) [cxf-api-2.7.14.redhat-1.jar:2.7.14.redhat-1]
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.ChainInitiationObserver.onMessage(ChainInitiationObserver.java:121) [cxf-api-2.7.14.redhat-1.jar:2.7.14.redhat-1]
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.AbstractHTTPDestination.invoke(AbstractHTTPDestination.java:249)
    at org.jboss.wsf.stack.cxf.RequestHandlerImpl.handleHttpRequest(RequestHandlerImpl.java:97)
    at org.jboss.wsf.stack.cxf.transport.ServletHelper.callRequestHandler(ServletHelper.java:131)
    at org.jboss.wsf.stack.cxf.CXFServletExt.invoke(CXFServletExt.java:88)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.handleRequest(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:286)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.doPost(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:206)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:754) [jboss-servlet-api_3.0_spec-1.0.2.Final-redhat-2.jar:1.0.2.Final-redhat-2]
    at org.jboss.wsf.stack.cxf.CXFServletExt.service(CXFServletExt.java:136)
    at org.jboss.wsf.spi.deployment.WSFServlet.service(WSFServlet.java:140) [jbossws-spi-2.3.1.Final-redhat-1.jar:2.3.1.Final-redhat-1]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847) [jboss-servlet-api_3.0_spec-1.0.2.Final-redhat-2.jar:1.0.2.Final-redhat-2]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:295) [jbossweb-7.5.7.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.5.7.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214) [jbossweb-7.5.7.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.5.7.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.gatein.wsrp.servlet.ServletAccessFilter.doFilter(ServletAccessFilter.java:56) [wsrp-common-2.3.4.Final-redhat-1.jar:2.3.4.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:246) [jbossweb-7.5.7.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.5.7.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214) [jbossweb-7.5.7.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.5.7.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:231) [jbossweb-7.5.7.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.5.7.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:149) [jbossweb-7.5.7.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.5.7.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:420) [jbossweb-7.5.7.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.5.7.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.as.web.security.SecurityContextAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityContextAssociationValve.java:169) [jboss-as-web-7.5.0.Final-redhat-21.jar:7.5.0.Final-redhat-21]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:150) [jbossweb-7.5.7.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.5.7.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:97) [jbossweb-7.5.7.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.5.7.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:102) [jbossweb-7.5.7.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.5.7.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:344) [jbossweb-7.5.7.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.5.7.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:854) [jbossweb-7.5.7.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.5.7.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:653) [jbossweb-7.5.7.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.5.7.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:926) [jbossweb-7.5.7.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.5.7.Final-redhat-1]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [rt.jar:1.8.0_45]
Caused by: org.apache.ws.security.WSSecurityException: Failed Authentication : Subject has not been created
    at org.jboss.wsf.stack.cxf.security.authentication.SubjectCreatingInterceptor.setSubject(SubjectCreatingInterceptor.java:161)
    at org.jboss.wsf.stack.cxf.security.authentication.SubjectCreatingInterceptor$CustomValidator.verifyUnknownPassword(SubjectCreatingInterceptor.java:236)
    at org.apache.ws.security.validate.UsernameTokenValidator.validate(UsernameTokenValidator.java:110)
    at org.apache.ws.security.processor.UsernameTokenProcessor.handleUsernameToken(UsernameTokenProcessor.java:181)
    at org.apache.ws.security.processor.UsernameTokenProcessor.handleToken(UsernameTokenProcessor.java:67)
    at org.apache.ws.security.WSSecurityEngine.processSecurityHeader(WSSecurityEngine.java:402)
    at org.apache.cxf.ws.security.wss4j.WSS4JInInterceptor.handleMessage(WSS4JInInterceptor.java:272)
    ... 32 more
Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: JBWS024047: Authentication failed, principal=tester
    at org.jboss.wsf.stack.cxf.security.authentication.SubjectCreator.createSubject(SubjectCreator.java:101)
    at org.jboss.wsf.stack.cxf.security.authentication.SubjectCreatingInterceptor.createSubject(SubjectCreatingInterceptor.java:245)
    at org.jboss.wsf.stack.cxf.security.authentication.SubjectCreatingInterceptor.setSubject(SubjectCreatingInterceptor.java:155)
    ... 38 more
```

And from Liferay `server.log`:

```
An error was discovered processing the <wsse:Security> header.
    at org.apache.axis.message.SOAPFaultBuilder.createFault(SOAPFaultBuilder.java:222)
    at org.apache.axis.message.SOAPFaultBuilder.endElement(SOAPFaultBuilder.java:129)
    at org.apache.axis.encoding.DeserializationContext.endElement(DeserializationContext.java:1087)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.endElement(AbstractSAXParser.java:609)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanEndElement(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:1782)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:2973)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:606)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:117)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:510)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:848)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:777)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:141)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(AbstractSAXParser.java:1213)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(SAXParserImpl.java:649)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl.parse(SAXParserImpl.java:333)
    at org.apache.axis.encoding.DeserializationContext.parse(DeserializationContext.java:227)
    at org.apache.axis.SOAPPart.getAsSOAPEnvelope(SOAPPart.java:696)
    at org.apache.axis.Message.getSOAPEnvelope(Message.java:435)
    at org.apache.axis.handlers.soap.MustUnderstandChecker.invoke(MustUnderstandChecker.java:62)
```

I am very new to web services/SOAP/etc. and am not sure how to troubleshoot this. I have created identical users several times on both servers but no luck. I have tried to use Fiddler to try to further troubleshoot the SOAP headers but did not glean much useful information. I would appreciate any tips or pointers.

Comment: WSRP is a dead protocol and the results is ugly. Change your way guy if you are in time..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per Red Hat support, this is a bug. Please see:

https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1258530